# add small text in select option html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have select options. I want to add a small text in options. Like my 2nd option have

```
<option>Gen Z (2000 &amp; later)</option>
```

in this option I want (2000 & later) bit smaller font size than Gen Z. I tried  or  and custom font size by css. but nothing works. 
If I use `option{font-size:8px}`. This works but it decrease the size of all the text in option.

Kindly tell me if there is any way to do this.

Thank you

```
<select class="form-control">
<option>No Preference</option>
<option>Gen Z (2000 &amp; later)</option>
<option>Millennial <small>(1980-1999)</small></option>
<option>Gen X <small>(1965-1979)</small></option>
<option>Boomer <small>(1946-1964)</small></option>
<option>Silent Gen <small>(1945 &amp; earlier)</small></option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can't use an select for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select/7208814

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what the OP is asking simply cannot be done. You cannot style individual sections of select option text.